# Where is address in hex IDA pro, disassembler

Tags: assembly, hex, ida, disassembly

ASM

```
......
.text:000000000062D153   lea   rax, aaa ; "aaaaaaaaaaa"
.text:000000000062D15A   lea   rdx, bbb ; "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
......
.rodata:0000000000F63221 aaa     db 'aaaaaaaaaaa',0                                               
.rodata:0000000000F6322D bbb     db 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',0 
.rodata:0000000000F6323E align 20h
......
```

HEX

```
......
000000000062D153  48 8D 05 C7 60 93 00
000000000062D15A  48 8D 15 CC 60 93 00
......
```

I dont understand, where this address "aaa"(F63221) in hex 48 8D 05 C7 60 93 00 ?
How to replace a to b in hex, and get ?

```
 .text:000000000062D15A                 lea     rdx, aaa ; "aaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
000000000062D153  48 8D 05 C7 60 93 00
```

Is actually :

```
lea    rax, [rip+0x9360c7]
```

This is a RIP relative address, and the offset is in the 4 last bytes of the instruction (`C7 60 93 00` = `0x009360C7`). This addressing mode refers to memory relative to the next instruction (not the current, because RIP points to the next instruction). If you do the math, you will see that `0x0062D15A` + `0x009360C7` is `0x00F63221`.

To refer to `bbb`, you need to calculate `0x00F6322D` - (`0x0062D15A` + `7`). This gives an offset value of `0x9360CC`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought about the difference of addresses, but considered from the beginning of the instructions